# Колледж vs училище

Tags: выбор-слова

A Quizlet flashcard set had both these words translated as "college". Maybe different kinds of colleges? Technical school?

Answer (score 3):

*Училище* means "vocational school", a place where one learns a trade that requires a skill but doesn't require a degree. There used to be *профессионально-техническое училище* (all kinds of blue collar trades), *музыкальное училище, педагогическое училище, военное училище* etc.

During the influx of English words in the 1990s, most of them renamed themselves *колледж*, following the trend.

Before that, the word *колледж* wasn't really used in Russian other than to translate the English word "college" (in all its meanings).

When applied to educational facilities in modern Russia, these two words mean pretty much the same: "a trade school". The difference between them is purely stylistic, and each particular school picks the one it likes best.